# Is it possible to build a formula that prevents negative numbers?

Tags: arithmetic

I have a calculation that goes like this:

$$\text{<any positive number>} - 100$$

As long as the result is a positive number it is acceptable.

However, if the result is a negative number, I need the outcome to calculate to  zero. A negative number is not permissible.

Is such a formula possible?

---

**Update 1**

This is for use in a [CSS **`calc`** function](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#calc-notation) .

```
 .class { margin-top: calc(100vh - 100px); }
```

I don't want the margin to ever be negative.

The function accepts only basic math operators (+, -, /, *).

---

**Update 2**

Some have mentioned in the comments that this question is more about CSS than math, and belongs in Stack Overflow.

However, this question is seeking a mathematical formula which has nothing to do with CSS (or coding, for that matter). It just happens to go into a CSS function.

Comment: This site is about mathematics. If you have any questions about CSS or related things I suggest asking them on StackOverflow instead.

Comment: @kamil09875, I apologize for the late update, but this is not a question about CSS. It's a question about the mathematical expression that goes into the function, which has nothing to do with CSS.

Comment: Also, I upvoted your answer and others which answer the original question. Thanks.

Comment: This really is a css question - you need to know whether css supports max or absolute value or an if statement to use one of the answers. If not, you need a css hack. Posting on a better SE site is more likely to find one.

Comment: @EthanBolker, I didn't know how to build such a formula, so I didn't know where to target or how to narrow down the question. The `calc` function only accepts addition (+), subtraction (-), multiplication (*) and division (/).  https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#calc-notation

Comment: @Michael_B It is about CSS, because we are restricted to use the language of CSS.

Comment: If such a calculation is possible using basic mathematical operators (as listed in previous comment), I would appreciate an answer. If not, I'll come back in 24 hours and accept the community choice.

Comment: Does the range checking example (scroll down in the link you provided) solve your problem?

Comment: @EthanBolker, I appreciate the research. Some CSS properties, such as `width` and `height` *do not* allow negative values. So regardless of the `calc` result, it can never be less than zero, and this question wouldn't be necessary. Some properties, however, such as `margin`, do take negative values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can write the $\max$ as

$\max(x,y) = (|x-y|+x+y)/2$

thus you would like $\max( x-100,0)$ that can be written as 
$$ (|x-100|+x-100)/2 $$

Comment: I would like to add that $|x-100|$ may be written as $\sqrt{(x-100)^2}$ if one would like to use only "traditional" operations.

Comment: but how do you get square root with only `+ - * /`?

Comment: You cannot, to rigorously define the square root for any value $y$ in an interval, it is needed the axiom of the supremum.

Answer (score 5):

It is

$$z=\max(y,0)$$

where $y$ is your number.

Comment: Correct, of course. I wonder whether the OP will accept "max" as a formula.

Comment: @EthanBolker there are several representations of this function, except the $\max$ you can use absolute value, definition by cases etc. I think this one is the most elegant.

Comment: I agree on the elegance. I wonder if any of them will suit the OP. He may have a narrow notion of what "function" means.

Answer (score 1):

$ y= \begin{cases} x-100 , x>100,\\0 ,0<x\le100 \end{cases} $

Comment: This answers the original question but not the update. Can you edit your answer to address the update?